# Adjective or Adverb: unconsciously vs unconscious

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Position of Adjectives: An adjective nearly always appears immediately before the noun or noun phrase that they modify. The source is [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adjectives.htm).

But if you look at the following sentence, the adjective "unconscious" doesn't appear before a noun, why? The source of the 1st and 3rd are [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconsciously). The source of the second is [here](http://www.justdriving.net/driving-theory-test-question-bank/accidents.html).

> 1. He was knocked unconscious by a fall.
> 2. An injured motorcyclist is lying unconscious in the road.
> 3. She was unconscious for three days after the accident.

In the 2nd sentence, why can't it be "unconsciously"? Lying is a verb, so "lying unconsciously" is valid, is itn't?

Comment: That's not a definition of *adjective*, that's close to a definition of attributive function.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/is-it-possible-to-use-adjectives-as-adverbs) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate).

Comment: @snailboat sorry for the mistake. I meant "Position of Adjectives". I updated the question and added the source.

Comment: I'm not sure, I can post others answer. But the best answer for this question is [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/is-it-possible-to-use-adjectives-as-adverbs), answered by snailboat

Comment: A related question: [“waterway … flowed sombre” - Should Joseph Conrad have used an adverb, not an adjective?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/waterway-flowed-sombre-should-joseph-conrad-have-used-an-adverb-not-an/46391#46391)

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any context where *lying unconsciously* could mean anything except *telling lies without knowing they are lies*.

As to *why* it can't mean *prone and unconscious*, I think it's at least partly because the adverbial ***-ly*** suffix attached to an adjective *xxxx* normally means *in an xxxx manner*. You can't normally *lie [prone]* in an unconscious ***manner***, but you can certainly ***be*** unconscious in that position.

Taking a different adjective, it's perfectly possible to *lie quietly* (or *sit quietly*, to choose a more common verb/adverb pairing). OP's particular example is invalid for semantic, rather than "grammatical" reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's the motorcyclist that was unconscious, not the lying.

e.g.

> He was tapping his finger unconsciously

Where it is the tapping that is unconscious

vs.

> Unconscious, he was tapping his finger

which would mean he was tapping his finger while asleep.

Another way to think of it is that both "lying" and "unconscious" are describing the person. Then the position becomes a common one for an adjective: Noun was adjective.