# Two questions about the verb "knock"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Consider ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=7M-V0cqNMHAC&pg=RA1-PA28&lpg=RA1-PA28&dq=knocked%20inert&source=bl&ots=_BRzgVwqKd&sig=jLh8z2WlbyyZ7Y251ts6mGT2GMY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK0tWak8PNAhUFSJoKHcmpDTcQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=knocked%20inert&f=false)):

> 1. A goldfinch flew across the field, struck the glass and was knocked inert.
> 2. The large birds flew together and struck the glass; they were knocked into a stupor.

---

**Question 1 :** Would you tell me how the adjective can be used after verb in sentence #1? I am saying that since I never saw the verb ***knock*** being used as a linking verb.

**Question 2:** As far as I know, stupor is a state and [*knock someone into something*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+into) means to make someone strike something. Has  the  verb ***knock*** used figuratively? I want to know more about it.

Comment: He was knocked out.  He was knocked unconscious. The baseball player knocked the ball out of the park.  They slapped him silly.

Comment: You have transitive **knock** being cast in the passive.  The birds were knocked unconscious by the collision.

Comment: **unconscious** and **out** are complements of the verb indicating the resulting state of that which got knocked.

Comment: (+1) @TRomano So far, The only thing that came to my mind, in terms of multiple parts verbs, was phrasal verbs. That is great

Comment: The blade must be honed sharp.  The wrinkles need to be ironed out. But the wrinkles don't need to be made unconscious.

Comment: 1 See [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/is-it-possible-to-use-adjectives-as-adverbs) 2. 'knock' is not being used figuratively. You are can use 'knock into (a state)'–for example, *knocked into a stupor*; just like you can say 'knocked senseless' (see 1).

Comment: Similar patterns: *The coffee was served hot. He was caught off guard. She left the room angry.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Why would someone say **She left the room angry** rather than **She left the room angrily**?

Comment: @Cardinal Because they didn't mean to talk about how she left the room, but rather what she was like when/after she left the room. (BTW, the first question of this question is pretty similar to this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/is-it-possible-to-use-adjectives-as-adverbs.)

Comment: *She left the room angry* is ambiguous, as it could be the *room* that was left angry, as in 'the people who stayed in the room'. @DamkerngT.  Also, *angry* could be used as a flat adverb here, and thus equivalent to *angrily*. So maybe [Cardinal's comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94723/two-questions-about-the-verb-knock?noredirect=1#comment184840_94723) asking about the two sentences is best covered as a new question and answer.

Comment: @AlanCarmack That interpretation would be rather strange. It was like saying *This is the car red we were talking about yesterday* (instead of *the red car*). I'd say though reading that *angry* as a flat adverb may be possible, it's unlikely. This comment is just my opinion, anyway.

Comment: *She left the room angry* (with *angry* applying to *room*) is the same form as *Her departure left the room speechless*. @DamkerngT.

Comment: @AlanCarmack and Cardinal, I'm a bit too tired to explain this myself. I'll let this grammar book explain this point instead: *[English Grammar: A Resource Book for Students](https://books.google.com/books?id=dSnjAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA169)* by Roger Berry, page 169.

Comment: Cardinal, it is not mainly a matter of verbs (like in the case of which verbs takes *to-infinitive* and which takes *-ing form* or *gerund* and which can take both). It is a matter of sentence construction. See [this comment](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2716#comment-89224) and also google "predicative complements" or "predicate complements". Also, I hate to link the [Is it possible to use adjectives as adverbs?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/is-it-possible-to-use-adjectives-as-adverbs.) for the third time in one comment trail, but there you go.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41671/discussion-on-question-by-cardinal-two-questions-about-the-verb-knock).

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1 : Would you tell me how the **adjective can be used after
>   verb** in sentence #1? I am saying that since I never saw the verb knock
>   being used as a linking verb.

- A goldfinch flew across the field, struck *the glass* and was *knocked* inert.

  - 'Knock' is used as a linking verb in the sense that two objects collided and therefore produced a result, this result being the "inert" state which the bird now finds himself. With a verb like this, you need the adjective to describe *how* he was knocked - was he knocked silly? Knocked unconscious? Knocked simply off-balance? The adjective describes which state the thing being knocked becomes as a result of the knocking.

> Question 2: As far as I know, stupor is a state and knock someone into
>   something means to make someone strike something. Has the verb knock
>   used figuratively? I want to know more about it.

- The large birds flew together and struck the glass; they were knocked into a stupor.

  - Again, this is the same thing as above, just a little different. Because they knocked the glass, they went into a stupor. The implied meaning here is the word 'upon,' in two cases. The new sentence might read like this: "The large birds flew together and struck upon the glass; upon doing so, they were knocked into a stupor."

    - It can be used figuratively. The example you linked to is very literal, and closest to the actual definition of the word 'knock.' It's a very active verb in the sense that there is only one thing that can happen when someone is knocked - they are knocked, literally. They fall over. They stumble, etc. But with idioms and phrases, this verb acts completely different. Some examples are: [knock into shape](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+into+shape), [knock the habit](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+the+habit), etc. Keep in mind though that there are multiple definitions of knock, such as which apply only to what you'd do to a door, for example. Some mean 'punch.' Some are lighter than that and only mean 'tapped,' or something similar. It's all about context, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just for curisity, are you native? I checked your profile, but it seems you did not edit your prifile.