# "Did I hear that correctly?" or "Did I hear that correct?" Which one is correct?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, complements, adjuncts

This is a conversation in the film "**A Wish for Christmas**", you can download its subtitle on the internet

The boss is talking on the phone:

> **Boss**: Frankly, the way things are going,    Christmas is turning into
>   one big, giant headache. I know. Christmas isn't all it's cracked up
>   to be. I've tried to make it work. If you don't like it, then maybe
>   you should talk to him. I have to go. Christmas is not happening. I'm
>   sorry.

After that, a man says

> **Man**: Uh, ahem, did I hear that **correct**, boss? Because I got five
>   employees coming in to work on Christmas,  but if it's not
>   happening...
>
> **Boss**: What? No, no. That's not what I meant. No.   It's happening.

My concern is that the sentence "did I hear that correct?" sounds unfamiliar

Because "**Correct**" is an adjective & is never an adverb.

So, I expect he says "***Did I hear that correctly***?" "**correctly**" is an adverb & modify the verb "**hear**"

However we also have object compliment,

Eg: I painted the house black. "Black" is an adjective and a compliment of the house [Source](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/hyper/index-fra.html?lang=fra&page=objcompl.html)

Besides, we've got this structure "**hear somebody/something doing something**" in [the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hear?q=hear)

Eg: He could hear a dog **barking**. I would say "**barking**" is a compliment of "**a dog**"

I am not sure if I can say "**I hear that correct**", in this case "**correct**" is an adjective and a compliment of "**that**"

So, Which one is correct?

Do you say
"Did I hear that correctly?" or "Did I hear that correct?"

Comment: Using "correct" ae an adverb is substandard English.  We should use correctly  in the sentence in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Correct" can be used as a [flat adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) in certain dialects. In fact, that includes the dialect of American English that I speak. It is pretty informal. You can find plenty of examples of this online:

- > Did I hear you correct, 1500?” “You heard correct.”
  >   <sub>[Small Fires in the Sun: First Were Natchez, Then Came the Spanish, the French & The African Slaves](https://books.google.com/books?id=485fDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT89)</sub>
- > The thing is, even though we all know about Green Bay, if I hear you correct, then you find out the truth long before everybody else.
  >   <sub>[A Brief History of Seven Killings: A Novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=XR90AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA545)</sub>
- > The only time that most hear it correct is when they hear me talk.
  >   <sub>[Collected Wisdom: American Indian Education](https://books.google.com/books?id=0kV2AAAAMAAJ&q="+hear+it+correct")</sub>

Some flat adverbs are considered Standard English, some aren't.  Given that I can't find "correct" (as an adverb) in any dictionary, it should not be considered Standard English. (Of course, just because it is found in a dictionary [does not mean that everyone will find it acceptable](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wc/when-adverbs-fall-flat/).)

The [history of why flat adverbs are disliked by prescriptivists](https://books.google.com/books?id=SXJoAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA96) is interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

The man should have stated it using the adverb "correctly" rather than the adjective "correct" because an adverb is used to modify a verb:

> "Did I hear that ***correctly***, boss?

Using "correct" as an adverb is, indeed, substandard English as Khan states above.

I hope this might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: It's one thing to say something is not standard English. It's entirely different to call it "substandard English". "Correct" is used as an adverb in my dialect, like many of the results [here](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1440&bih=733&ei=o3xMWtXJDsyhggfdqKuoDg&q="you+heard+that+correct") show.

Comment: We teach "standard" English here, so if it is not standard, it's "**substandard**". If you think it's an affront, it's not, but there is no definition that says "correct" is an adverb in any dictionary. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/correct. If you have not noticed, this answer has been approved. I rest my case.

Comment: I could have also used "**nonstandard**" if I had wanted to, but I felt Khan's use of "substandard" was appropriate. I mean, if it's not standard, then it's substandard (below standard) or nonstandard (not standard).

Comment: I think the problem is that "substandard" implies "bad, incorrect, not valid".  But if that's how speakers of (some dialects of) English actually speak, then it's not "substandard" for them.

Comment: Any deviation from standard English is either substandard or nonstandard English, and those are just substandard or nonstandard qualities in those dialects relative to standard English. You seem to be looking at it from only the standpoint of your specific dialect; I'm looking at it from a relative standpoint when compared to standard form. That doesn't mean your dialect is completely nonstandard; it just means that that is a substandard or nonstandard aspect of it, and I'm sure it's only for some speaker rather than all.